# Need to setup the QField Android Platform with Android Studio

Tags: qfield, android

I have seen the source code of the QField System, FYI (https://github.com/opengisch/QField/tree/master).

I need to set up/Build and Run the Android Platform Alone in Android Studio from the above source, how can I set up the Source Code with Android Studio(Windows) to Build the Android application?